# Saving html data in variable from completion handler in Swift WKWebView

Tags: javascript, html, swift, wkwebview, wknavigationdelegate

I'm trying to scrape data from a website, and the data I want is in a span tag. So far, what I've done is:

```
var str: Any?
webView.evaluateJavaScript("innerDoc.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML", completionHandler: 
    { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
       str = html

    })
print(str)
```

But when I do this I just get nil. If I put `print(html)` in place of `str = html` I get the output I want.

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I store that value in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating JavaScript takes the WKWebView some time. In this case the `print(str)` statement most likely takes place before the JS script is evaluated. Try moving it inside the completion handler of your evaluation statement and see if it works.